# Django REST Framework - queryset filter only for authenticated user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to `Django REST Framework`. I think I have gone messed up in it as sometimes it feels like DRF is easy to understand but later it got messed up.

I have a `contacts` application.

**contacts/models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)


class ContactEmail(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()


class ContactPhoneNumber(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Each contact is related some authenticated user.

**contacts/serializers.py**

```
class ContactPhoneNumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactPhoneNumber
        fields = ('id', 'phone')


class ContactEmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactEmail
        fields = ('id', 'email')


class ContactSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    phone_numbers = ContactPhoneNumberSerializer(source='contactphonenumber_set', many=True)
    emails = ContactEmailSerializer(source='contactemail_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth',
                   'phone_numbers', 'emails')
```

and **contacts/views.py**

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, AdminAuthenticationPermission,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user_id=self.request.user)
```

as far till here, I followed the doc of `Django REST Framework` but it displays all contacts instead of showing only user's contacts.

To achieve that, I added `get_queryset()`

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Contact.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    ...
```

But it started giving error as

```
assert queryset is not None, '`base_name` argument not specified, and could ' \
AssertionError: `base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.
```

after doing some research, I found to add third parameter to router

**app/urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'contacts', ContactViewSet, 'contacts') # added 'contacts' here

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls))
]
```

But instead of solving the issue, it generated a new error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked 
relationship using view name "contact-detail". 
You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

again after doing some research, found solution to define `url` in `searializers.py`. So, I updated my `contacts/serializers.py`

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    phone_numbers = ...
    emails = ...

    url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='contacts:detail'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth',
                   'phone_numbers', 'emails')
```

But now, it has started giving a new error

```
'Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, '
AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.
```

**Is'nt there some simple way just to filter objects based on `request.user` as my application is user based and every authenticated user can view/edit/delete his own data only.**

**Also, is there any way to get this issue resolved as I'm confused here which Relational field it is talking about?**

Comment: What your `url` field should show?

Comment: https://restframework.herokuapp.com/ checkout this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solved my issue

set `read_only=True` to `url`

```
url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    view_name='contacts:detail',
    read_only=True
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I havent worked with ModelViewSet.
But in a regular APIView, you can do this:

```
class SingleProject(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        project_id = request.query_params.get('id')
        ans = Project.objects.filter(id=project_id)
        serializer = EagerGetProjectSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

so maybe something like this:

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, AdminAuthenticationPermission,)
```

Comment: your second code will give `unresolved reference self` as the `self` is not defined

Comment: it is required to override get_queryset() method instead of using attribute